# Date format is not changing in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I am trying to change date format in Google Chart so that instead of date it needs to show only Month name. i have a dynamic data is coming .

I have used

```
 hAxis: {
            format: 'MMMM',
           
        }
```

which is not working.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckht4Lbo/)

Any idea.

Comment: you're passing a string -- `'2020-11-05T18:30:00.000Z'` -- for the above option to work, you need to pass a date -- `new Date('2020-11-05T18:30:00.000Z')`

Comment: @WhiteHat i am passing the date with new  Date

Comment: not in the above fiddle -- see [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juwoL65s/)...